# Remove Html Tags in Title Attribute without JavaScript

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, html

**Approval_notes__c** is a formula field that contains html tags.

I display it in a **Lightning web component**, the **lightning-formatted-rich-text** component work perfectly and display the text correctly.
I want to display the text also as help note in the **title** attribute. Is there a way to remove html tags from it without using JavaScript?

```
<lightning-formatted-rich-text title={Approval_notes__c} class="slds-truncate" value={Approval_notes__c}></lightning-formatted-rich-text>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can set `title` attribute separetely for `lightning-formatted-rich-text` tag

**html**

```
<lightning-formatted-rich-text
    title={preparedTitle}
    value={Approval_notes__c}>
</lightning-formatted-rich-text>
```

**js**

```
...
get preparedTitle(){
    //prepare desired title without special symbols
    return this.Approval_notes__c.replace(.....//correct regex goes here)
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I am trying to do that without Js

Comment: unfortunately, it is not possible for now to do just by means of markup, as lwc markup do not have any markup expressions (but aura has) It will require an additional step to prepare the sanitized string for the title (in apex, or in js)